# Magento 2 error: definition specified by xsi:type is blocked

Tags: magento2

I am trying to create my custom widget and I have my `widget.xml` file like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<widgets xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../Magento/Widget/etc/widget.xsd">
<widget id="WidgetId" class="WidgetClass">
    <label>Widget label</label>
    <parameters>
        <parameter name="firstParameter" xsi:type="string" required="true" visible="true" sort_order="0" >
            <label>First parameter label</label>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="secondParameter" xsi:type="number" required="true" visible="true" sort_order="1" >
            <label>Second parameter label</label>
        </parameter>
    </parameters>
</widget>
```

And now I got an error:

`The type definition 'string', specified by xsi:type, is blocked or not validly derived from the type definition of the element declaration.`

Could someone tell me why it shows and how to solve it?

Comment: instead of using `string` and `number` in `xsi:type` use `text`

Comment: make sure after changing flush cache

Comment: @AmanAlam but I don't want that second parameter as text. It has to be a number

Comment: Which version of magento you are using.

Comment: @AmanAlam 2.2.3